# copy string in c using pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Code copy string in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *copyString(char *,char *);
void main()
{
    char *first = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),10);
    char *second = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),10);
    printf("Enter first string:\t");
    scanf("%s",first);
    printf("%s",copyString(first,second));
}
char *copyString(char *a,char *b)
{
    int i=0;
    while(*(a+i)!='\0')
    {
        *(b+i)=*(a+i);
        i++;
    }
    *(b+i)='\0';
    return b;
}
```

**`Case 1:`**

---

**Input :** Hello

**Output :** Hello

**`Case 2:`**

---

**Input :** Hello World

**Output :** Hello

So, my question is whether `space` is considered as `newline/null` ?? Because, in second case, it shows like this..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, `scanf` stops reading the standard input stream when a space character `' '` is encountered. To fix it, you can use a scanset.

```
scanf("%[^\n]", first);
```

Comment: why so ?? space is also a character. isn't ??

Comment: yes that's how scanf() is defined. It will stop reading after first whitespace

Comment: `[^\n]` what does it mean ?? i believe, this is used for checking pattern for new line. But, my question is instead of `%s`, we have used `%[^\n]` and it works. how ??

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` stops reading after the first whitespace by default. Use `fgets()` or `gets()`[unsafe]. With regards to *why* it is this way, you might want to read the POSIX pages here: http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/scanf/ and ISO C standards here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf. It has a lengthy description on how `scanf()` and `fscanf()`(and all other standard C functions) should work. These are generally followed guidelines on how functions in C library *should* work.

All compilers strive hard to create POSIX compliant standard-c libraries that work the same across most UNIX'ish platforms.

The standard C functions are actually defined here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's because stops reading after whitespace when you input it the string. So you actaully only have `"Hello"` in your `first` string, not `"Hello world"`.

Use `fgets()` to read the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested `scanf` stops at the first whitespace, you could use `fgets` instead to read the whole line. And when you get that working allocate more space, because "Hello World" is 12 bytes not 10.

Comment: sorry... that was just an example.. my main question was... it is not reading after space character

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` is scanning just one string for two strings to be scanned you should write:

```
      scanf("%s %s",first,second);
```

Similarly for more strings to be scanned you should do like this that is giving as many `%s` as many strings you want to scan.

Answer (score 0):

The scanf function here will read input until it encounters whitespace.   You will need to implement a readline function.

Answer (score 0):

use #include  and utilize this function strcpy of string.h lib. following is the example:

```
    strcpy(first, second);
```

This should run fine.